# Android Movie not working in devices

Tags: android, animation

I am working with android.I had created an android app with animation view using Movie.But its not working in android devices.Is it possible in all android devices??

Answer (score 0):

I would check first if the movie is played with the default application of android.
this will let you know if the problem is in the app you've written, the movie itself or the device.